# Change of measures with Wiener process

Tags: r, monte-carlo

I am trying to test importance sampling for a simple a Wiener process $W_t$ in R:

```
set.seed(123)
Z <- matrix(rnorm(12*1000),12,1000)
W <- apply(Z,2,cumsum) #Wiener process simulated 1000 times for 12 periods
B <- W-(1:12) #Brownian motion with drift -1
w <- exp(-W[12,]) #Radon-Nikodym derivative (actually w <- exp(-W[12,]-12/2))
mean(B[12,]) #-11.973
sum(W[12,]*(w/sum(w))) #-7.881 to compare with -12!
```

I think that the estimate with the derivative is not really "precise"! Any suggestions to improve the accuracy, besides increasing the number of simulations?